# Can anyone please tell me what's wrong in this caml query code?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, caml, sharepoint-api

The Query:

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name='Document Type' LookupId='True' />            
    <Value Type='Text'>Standards(STA)</Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>
<OrderBy>
 <FieldRef Name='Number' Ascending='False'/>
</OrderBy>
<RowLimit>1</RowLimit>"
```

Code Context:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register tagprefix="WebPartPages" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register tagprefix="SharePoint" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<html>

<head>
<meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />
<meta name="ProgId" content="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" />


<h1>T-Site</h1>

 <script runat="server" type="">            

protected void sevak(object sender, EventArgs e)

string lastitem;
try
{

  using (SPSite objsite = new SPSite("http://..."))
  {
    using (SPWeb objWeb = objSite.OpenWeb())
    {
      SPList objList = objWeb.Lists["...."];
      SPQuery objQuery = new SPQuery();

      objQuery.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Document Type' LookupId='True' />            <Value Type='Text'>Standards(STA)</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Number' Ascending='False'/></OrderBy><RowLimit>1</RowLimit>";

      objQuery.Folder = objList.RootFolder;
      SPListItemCollection colItems = objList.GetItems(objQuery);

      if (colItems.Count>0)
      {
        lastitem=colItems(0);
      }
      else 
      { 
        Label1.Text="noItem";
      }
    }
  }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  return ex;
}

Label1.Text= "lastitem";
```

```
<SharePoint:CssLink runat="server"></SharePoint:CssLink>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink runat="server" language="javascript" name="core.js">

</SharePoint:ScriptLink>

<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server" action="Page-2.aspx">
<p>


<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" id="Button1" OnClick="sevak" ></asp:Button>


</p>
<p><asp:Label runat="server" id="Label1"></asp:Label></p>
</form>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is the field reference "Document Type":

1. The `FieldRef` elements expects an internal name of the referenced field. If the column "Document Type" was created via the UI the internal name of this column is "Document_x0020_Type".
2. You specifed `LookupId="True"` which causes a lookup against the id of a lookup field, but you provided a text value. Depending of your field type you should either provider the numeric ID of the document type or omit the `LookupId="True"` part to query against the text of the lookup field.